# How to copy all text from an URL to the clipboard using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to make a script that copies all the text from an URL to the clipboard. I have tried to find a solution here, and on other forums, but I have not found anything that answers the question. I am pretty new to Python, so its hard to figure out by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the package [Pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/). Here's an example from their site

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
spam = pyperclip.paste()
```

If you have a variable that stores the URL you can sub that in for the argument in copy. Installation:

```sh
pip install pyperclip
```

Answer (score 0):

[clipboard](https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/)  is cross platform (Linux, Mac & Windows), i.e.:

Install:

```
pip install clipboard
```

---

Usage:

```
import clipboard
clipboard.copy("abc")  # put "abc" on clipboard
cb_text = clipboard.paste()  # get clipboard content
```

Comment: Note: The entirety of [`clipboard`](https://github.com/terryyin/clipboard/blob/master/clipboard.py) is `from pyperclip import copy, paste`. LOL